# How to nest modules in Android Studio

Tags: gradle, android-studio

I am trying to build a project with the following structure. It is an app that uses a library project using another library (Google Volley).

```
- MainProject
|-- ModuleProject
    |-- SubmoduleProject
```

ModuleProject/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile project(':SubmoduleProject')
}
```

ModuleProject/settings.gradle

```
include ':SubmoduleProject'
```

Android studio throws the following error:

```
Project with path ':SubmoduleProject' could not be found in project ':ModuleProject'
```

How can I build my project with nested libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `MainProject/settings.gradle` should have

`include 'ModuleProject', 'ModuleProject:SubmoduleProject'`

and the dependency will be `compile project(':ModuleProject:SubmoduleProject')`

Comment: Having an external module (with sources, not jar) doesn't nest it under Android Studio 1.5.1. It just adds both of them in the same level as siblings.